# Can you genetically engineer powerful Force users?

Tags: star-wars, biology

Can genetic engineering be used to create more powerful force users than naturally born life forms can become?

I was thinking about Vader's claim that the ability to destroy entire planets is nothing compared to the power that comes with the Force---I assume he was speaking figuratively. But what if this was taken literally? The most powerful Force users I can think of are Yoda and the Emperor. It would seem they can barely manipulate X-Wing sized objects (at least it appears Yoda *had* to concentrate considerably to pull the X-Wing out of the swamp). I suppose they would have no chance to actually influence entire planets, let alone destroy them.

If you accept Episode One's explanation, Force aptitude and midichlorean count are strongly positively correlated; So it would be a matter of just getting them into the humanoid.
But could you refine the genome of a humanoid enough to pump them full of midichloreans and allow them to actually move stellar objects telekinetically?

Comment: The most powerful Force users are Celestials Father, Daughhter and Son. WAY above the Jedi levels. Next one is probably Abeloth.

Comment: Also, Starkiller was (that's the usual example) able to pull a Star Destroyer out of orbit. Kyp pulled a SunDestroyer OUT of a star's interior?

Comment: @DVK - If I'm remembering right, in Kyp's case he didn't pull the SunCrusher out so much as just turn the autopilot on (still an impressive feat, given range and dexterity).  Of course, he _did_ have the disembodied spirit of a Sith Lord helping him...

Comment: Yoda, it can be argued, has trouble raising the X-wing because he was next to a source of dark side energy (in the Force Unleashed II novelisation, starkiller is severely affected by it).

Comment: In addition, Yoda hadn't used those "muscles" in 20 years, either. He was old, dying and out of practice at the time.

Comment: No, because otherwise someone would have done it. ;)

Answer (score 8):

The answer is yes. It has nothing to do with Star Wars canon (well sorta) and more to do with biology.

We know that Force powers are heritable (The Force is strong in Jedi families, especially Skywalker line but not exclusively).

As such, it's clear that there are some genetic predispositions to higher Midichloran counts.

The only difference between "genetic engineering" and plain old breeding of cattle (or Jedi in this case) is the logistics, one is achieved by random genetic mixing of parents, the other is deliberately induced.

Therefore, since you can breed for higher Midichlorean counts, you can also GMO for them.

QED.

Comment: Well the non-biology aspect was a bit hidden in the OP, sorry. Are the midichloreans really tied to genes, **and** do the midichloreans would resist such tampering.

Comment: @bitmask - they are inferred to be tied to genes because we are shown that Force sensitivity is clearly heritable; and Midichloreans don't themsleves travel from parent to offspring (Vader didn't lose any when Luke was born - no nitpicking about losing limbs at around the same time!)

Comment: And they wouldn't resist such tampering per se, since they don't resist natural breeding.

Comment: They did seem to protest when Plagueis messed with them. They do seem to have means to interfere with ... unnatural propagation.

Comment: @bitmask - that was because Plagueis was messing **with the Force**, not with biology.

Comment: I read in the novelisation of The Force Unleashed II that cloning force-sensitives was risky and they were unstable. Depending on how canon it is, that could be a strong argument against.

Comment: @Dakeyras - that was very (C-)canon. See Joruus C'baoth (spelling?), Jedi Master's clone from one of the earlier Thrawn novels. WAY insane.